# Very strange JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

So all this time I had no problem with this script. But all of sudden today, it began to behave strangely.

So I have a JavaScript page that loads inside an iframe.

This is injected into a page loaded via proxy.

`$(top.document).ready()`, throws an error saying Permission denied...

I was surprised, so I decided to try load a different page.

Then it was no longer complaining.

I rebooted my computer, and when I first loaded a page via proxy, as the iframe containing JavaScript was injected into that page, I got the same error again.

What is happening? Is this a problem on my server or my computer?

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Yup, this is almost certainly it.  Also, the answer below indicates that the session ID is different, which probably means that the two pages are being served by different virtual hosts (e.g. example.com and www.example.com).

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, there is a permissions problem and it likely has nothing to do with an error your computer, server, or otherwise, but is a design limitation/security feature of JavaScript.

JavaScript is able to access and/or alter other documents (e.g.: windows) other than its own (the one it is being executed fro) *if* that document comes from the same host.  This is known as the "[same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) [policy](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/jssec.html)."